# Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionNoteHolder. Android/Java (LinearLayoutManager is set)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I get Invalid view holder adapter error when pressing to return to the recycler view class after pressing an item. I've read some solutions here on stackoverflow but I'm not really sure how to implement that to my code as they seem to use other ways to do the recyclerview functionality in other answers?

If anyone could help and perhaps provide an example answer, that would be really helpful.

Note: I already read the post you tried to link with mine. But while it's the same issue, I am not sure how to implement the solution to my code. As I am already using linear layout manager like suggested.

My class for recyclerview:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class myRecyclerview extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference noteRef = db.collection("addColTest");
    private NoteAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myRecyclerview);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {

        Query query = noteRef.whereIn("searchID", Arrays.asList("0001", "0002"));
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();
        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_doIt);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Adapter code:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>{

    private onItemClickListener listener;

    public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Note model) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getHuvudrubrik());
        holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDatum());



    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note, parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(v);
    }

    public void deletePost(int position){
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDate;

        public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface onItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.testApp, PID: 13670
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionNoteHolder{bab5b31 position=3 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{9f84409 VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1744 #7f080138 app:id/recycler_view_doIt}, adapter:com.test.testApp.NoteAdapter@b65e60e, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@34f682f, context:com.test.testApp.myRecyclerview@ab75253
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:6156)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6339)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4255)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4010)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:2028)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:417)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:740)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

"Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionNoteHolder" seems to be the main cause.

Comment: post your error stacktrace and probably also adapters code would be helpful

Comment: @snachmsm Updated my post with adapter code and error.